Can't upload in Platformio and board is suddenly not detected in STM32CubeProgrammer
I'm using a Nucleo-H755ZI-Q. I used it together with Platformio and Arduino framework. In order to get Arduino to work I'm using this setup:
    [env:nucleo_h743zi]
    platform = ststm32
    board = nucleo_h743zi
    framework = arduino
    monitor_speed = 115200

This works fine using this board but suddenly it stopped working. I am getting this upload error:
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)

As well as the board is not connected STM32CubeProgrammer.
It is however discovered at port 13 but cannot upload. The COM LED is also red indicating there is a problem with the communication with the computer. I got a brand new USB cable and have tried others so it is not the cable.
I have two possible scenarios what has happened.

Since I have soldered the headers I have burned some component on the board. But maybe not so likely since it first worked and then stopped working.

Something has happened with the communication after using "wrong" but working board for uploading nucleo_h743zi.


Are there any way of factory reset my board Nucleo-H755ZI-Q in order to try to resolve what is wrong or any other recommendation? I have of course tried to reset with the reset button. But still the LED is red.
Thanks.

Not sure that nucleo_h743zi works with an H755...

Check your platformio.ini file. It should be correctly set up for the Nucleo-H755ZI-Q. The board field should match the exact board you are using. For the Nucleo-H755ZI-Q, the configuration should be:
[env:nucleo_h755zi_q]
platform = ststm32
board = nucleo_h755zi_q
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200


I know that. That board has however no arduino support so I hacked it a bit using nucleo_h743zi  instead. That worked to begin with. But maybe that what eventually made it corrupt
